# How to save HorizontalPager state when switching UI states in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

I have two UI states: `FIRST` and `SECOND`. In the `FIRST` state, I have a `HorizontalPager` and other widgets. In the `SECOND` state, I have a simple `Text` widget. I am switching between the UI states with a `Button` click.

I want to save the index of the current page in the `HorizontalPager` when I switch to the `SECOND` state, so that when I switch back to the `FIRST` state, the `HorizontalPager` opens on the same page.

For example, if I am on page 3 of the `HorizontalPager` and I click the `Button` to switch to the `SECOND` state, I want the `HorizontalPager` to open on page 3 when I switch back to the `FIRST` state.

Currently, when I switch back to the `FIRST` state, the `HorizontalPager` always opens on page 0.

> Note: The current page index of the HorizontalPager is only saved while the activity is active. This means that if the activity is destroyed (for example, when the user close the application or move to another activity), the HorizontalPager will start on page 0 when the activity is recreated.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ViewObersableTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
                    SaveVariable(pagerState, VariableViewModel())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SaveVariable**

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
fun SaveVariable(pagerState: PagerState, viewModel: VariableViewModel) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
            viewModel.currentIndex = page
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.setLastCurrentPage) {
        Log.e(">> LaunchedEffect", "${viewModel.currentIndex}")
    }
    SaveVariableItem(viewModel.currentIndex, viewModel.uiState, pagerState) {
        viewModel.changeUIi()
    }
}
```

**VariableViewModel**

```
class VariableViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var uiState by mutableStateOf(ScreenName.FIRST)
    var currentIndex by mutableStateOf(0)
    var setLastCurrentPage by mutableStateOf(false)
    fun changeUIi() {
        uiState = if (uiState == ScreenName.FIRST) {
            setLastCurrentPage = true
            ScreenName.SECOND
        } else {
            setLastCurrentPage = false
            ScreenName.FIRST
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenName**

```
enum class ScreenName {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}
```

**SaveVariableItem**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SaveVariableItem(
    currentIndex: Int,
    uiState: ScreenName,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    changeUiState: () -> Unit,
) {
    Column {
        when (uiState) {
            ScreenName.FIRST -> {
                ScreenFirstView(pagerState)
            }

            ScreenName.SECOND -> {
                ScreenSecondView(currentIndex, "SECOND")
            }
        }
        ChangeUiStateButton(changeUiState)
    }
}
```

**ChangeUiStateButton**

```
@Composable
fun ChangeUiStateButton(changeUiState: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = { changeUiState() }) {
        Text(text = "Add")
    }
}
```

**ScreenFirstView**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ScreenFirstView(pagerState: PagerState) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp),
            pageCount = 10,
            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            Text(
                text = "Page: $page",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenSecondView**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSecondView(currentIndex: Int, screenImage: String) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Text(text = "$currentIndex ==== $screenImage", color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

My github sample is [here](https://github.com/vivek-modi/ViewObersable).

```
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01"))
```

Comment: The code seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Did your `HorizontalPager` opens another page after coming from `SECOND` state? @Abhimanyu

Comment: I swiped horizontally to open "Page: 2" and then clicked on the "Add" button. It displays "2 === SECOND". Clicking on the "Add" button again switches back to the horizontal pager. My [repo](https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/stackoverflow-answers/blob/main/codebase/android/app/src/main/java/com/makeappssimple/abhimanyu/stackoverflowanswers/android/pager/PagerSample.kt) I used to test.

Comment: Yeah after coming from `SECOND` state which page `HorizontalPager` opens? If it opens 0 then I want to open Page 2.

Comment: I cannot use more than `bom:2023.05.01` version.

Comment: It opens the Page 2 for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255713/discussion-between-abhimanyu-and-kotlin-learner).

Answer (score 1):

Ive gotten this to work using state flows in the ViewModel. I cut the code down a little, but basically i had to add a LaunchedEffect into the composable containing the pager to update the PagerState upon composition using the saved page number in ViewModel. Not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this but this does work. heres the modified repo: https://github.com/Mr0btain/SavePagerState